# Consistent AsyncQuery timeout

Tags: query, timeout

I have several large queries that I expect will return 50K+ records, but i seem to get consistent timeouts. I changed my query to SORT BY Id, as recommended in some posts, this worked for a while but they are timing out again.

my query processing code looks like:

```
               Task<QueryResult<T>> task = client.QueryAsync<T>(soql);


                var currentResultList = task.Result.Records;
                listCount += currentResultList.Count;
                task.Wait();
                while (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(task.Result.NextRecordsUrl))
                {
                    task = client.QueryContinuationAsync<T>(task.Result.NextRecordsUrl);
                    processCallback(currentResultList);
                    apiCount++;
                    task.Wait();
                    currentResultList = task.Result.Records;
                    listCount += currentResultList.Count;
                }
                processCallback(currentResultList);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex, $"QueryAndProcess exception occurred for user {userName} for Query {soql} attempting to access {url}");
        }
```

I even tried to set the timeout on my own HTTP Client to 300 seconds but that make no difference, the exception occurs around 100-120 seconds.

```
                myClient = new HttpClient();
                myClient.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0,0,0,300);

                client = new ForceClient(instanceUrl, accessToken, apiVersion, myClient);
```

is there another way to set a longer timeout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am expecting 125k rows, 24 columns order by Id. I refactored the code to do two queries, and that works. I just need it to work for 6 months, by that time our system will no longer interface to SF.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether Salesforce will allow you to set longer timeouts. But when a query is timing out, it usually has to do with large record counts and query [selectivity](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=How-to-make-my-SOQL-query-selective&language=en_US&type=1).

You haven't posted your soql query itself, but how many records are in your table? Are you querying using indexes? You can read more about selectivity here: http://resources.docs.salesforce.com/rel1/doc/en-us/static/pdf/salesforce_query_search_optimization_developer_cheatsheet.pdf